# Program that reserves a seats in a few buses with various number of seats using dynamic allocation (malloc or calloc)

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays, calloc

I have to make a program that reserves a seats in a few buses (every bus have a different number of seats). I have to use malloc or calloc. It has to store info about name and surname and assign it to a seat. When seat are already occupied it has to give an info "seat already taken".
It also has to error handling.
I am begginer and I don't know what to do.

````
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max_name 32

int main()
{

    int n_buses,n_seats,zm;
    char*** tab;
    printf("Number of buses:");
    scanf("%d", &n_buses);

    tab=calloc(n_buses,sizeof(char**));

    for(int i=0;i<n_buses;i++)
    {
        printf("Number of seats in bus %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &zm);

        tab[i]=calloc(zm,sizeof(char*));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n_buses;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<max_name;j++)
        {
            tab[i][j]=calloc(max_name,sizeof(char));
        }
    }
 for(i=0;i<n_buses;i++)
    {
        if(tab[i]) free(tab[i]);
    }

    if(tab) free(tab);

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what to [not ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back away from this pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer and consider what would make an easy to use data type instead. You have buses, seats and passengers, so it makes sense to come a couple of structs to handle the abstraction for that:

```
typedef struct
{
  char* forename;
  char* lastname;
} passenger_t;

typedef struct
{
  int total_seats;
  passenger_t seat[];
} bus_t;
```

The last struct uses a trick called *flexible array member* to allow a variable-sized array at the end of a struct. You'd allocate memory for it as:

```
int seats = 100;
bus_t* my_bus = calloc( seats, sizeof(*my_bus) + sizeof(passenger_t[seats]) );
if(my_bus == NULL) { /* handle errors */ }

my_bus->total_seats = seats;
```

Now every seat is represented by an allocated `passenger_t` item in the `seat` array, each item with two pointers set to null by `calloc` (malloc wouldn't set them to null). You can use this to keep track of if a seat is free or taken.

Add a passenger:

```
if(n >= my_bus->total_seats)  // check that input is valid
{ 
  /* error handling */
}

if(my_bus->seat[n].forename != NULL)
{
  my_bus->seat[n].forename = ... /* allocate room for forename then strcpy to it*/

  my_bus->seat[n].lastname = ... /* allocate room for lastname then strcpy to it*/
}
```

Note how we only have *one* array here and one level of indirection, so this code turns out much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: First of all thank you so much. I have 2 more questions. I have to make an input with number of buses and number of seats for every single bus. How can I do it? And second one: user has to pick his own seat in a bus (for example: 3 4 - bus 3 seat 4). Should i just modify "n" in
 `if(my_bus->seat[n].forename != NULL)
{
  my_bus->seat[n].forename = ... /* allocate room for forename then strcpy to it*/

  my_bus->seat[n].lastname = ... /* allocate room for lastname then strcpy to it*/
}` @Lundin

Comment: @Adros Either as console input or through a file? Depending on how much data there is. And yes `n` is obviously a placeholder.

Comment: as a console input @Lundin